# android creating folder in root directory of the application

Tags: android

i am creating a module like i gave an access to camera for capturing the image and captured image should be visible only through the application not in gallery nor in file manager.And i created it.But only in some mobile like Samsung Mi mobiles images are not visible but in one plus and Sony images are  visible,why so,It is working in some mobiles and not in some mobiles

my code:

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave) {

    File direct = new File(getFilesDir() + "/CAT_IMG/");
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String fileName = "fav" + timeStamp + ".JPG";
    if (!direct.exists()) {
       // File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/CAT_IMG");
        direct.mkdir();
    }

    File file = new File(direct, fileName);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        createDirectoryAndSaveFile(photo);
        Log.e("URI", data.getExtras().get("data") + "");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You will need permissions, in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

> create directory:-

```
 File mydir = context.getDir("dirname", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!mydir.exists())
    {
         mydir.mkdirs();
    }
```

Comment: Actually here my directory name is  CAT_IMG i created it in root directory

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store your file in the app's root directory, you should create your directory inside the app's root directory using `getExternalFilesDir` like below:

```
File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
if (!storageDir.exists()) {
    storageDir.mkdirs();
}
```

And then put your image files inside the directory. Also don't forget to provide permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to read and write the storage like below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```